# Mongodb lookup -> match -> group taking too much time

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, query-optimization

I have a production app deployed and it generates a good amount of data every day. But this query usually takes around 15 seconds to complete. This is not okay. I want it way quickly. How do I rewrite this query for optimization and what went wrong here?

```js
        const activity_data = await Activity.aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'tokens',
                    localField: 'n_id',
                    foreignField: 'token_id',
                    as: 'sale_status'
                },
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    activity_type: 'FOR_SALE',
                    'sale_status.for_sale': true,
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$n_id',
                    createdAt: { $max: '$createdAt' },
                },
            },
            {
                $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
            },
            {
                $limit: 15
            }
        ]);
```

Comment: did you try creating compound index for "activity_type" and "sale_status.for_sale" together ?

Comment: @SmritiShikha No, I haven't tried that. What does it do?

Comment: refer this https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/. compound index basically creates a set of lookup for your mongo documents

Answer (score 0):

From a brief look at your query, you can do some minor tweaks to minimize the intermediate result.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      activity_type: "FOR_SALE"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tokens",
      let: {
        n: "$n_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$n",
                    "$token_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$for_sale",
                    true
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "sale_status"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "sale_status.for_sale": true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$n_id",
      createdAt: {
        $max: "$createdAt"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 15
  }
])
```

You can see the `activity_type` filter is moved to earlier stage. The `for_sale` filter is also moved into a sub-pipeline to minimize lookup results.

There are potentially more things to do if **more context on your query is given**. Say the `$lookup` could have been skipped if denormalizing the `for_sale` field into the `Activity` collection is an option.